# Is there any documentation which clearly states which CRM approach Salesforce follows?

Tags: design-patterns

Is there any clear documentation which clearly states which CRM approach Salesforce follows?

[This article](http://www.crmsoftware.com/types-of-crm-and-examples/) claims that Salesforce is a good example of an operational CRM.

Also [another article](http://www.crmsoftware.com/salesforce-review/) says that  core product is sales force automation (SFA), which means Salesforce is [Sales force automation also known as Sales force management system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sales_force_management_system) while in the previous article Sales force automation approach was defined just as subset of operational approach.

As wikipedia states, analytical CRM systems is to analyze customer data collected through multiple sources, and present it so that business managers can make more informed decisions. Since Salesforce allows to use reports and dashboards, it is possible to present data so that business managers can make more informed decisions, which means Salesforce also follows analytical CRM approach.

Also recently some new notion was created, Sales intelligence CRM. There is no article about this subject in wikipedia, only about [Sales intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sales_intelligence), where it is said that "Sales intelligence (SI) refers to technologies, applications and practices for the collection, integration, analysis, and presentation of information to help salespeople keep up to date with clients, prospect data and drive business." and "Unlike customer relationship management (CRM) and traditional business intelligence (BI) applications, SI provides real-time analysis of current sales data and assists with suggesting and delivering actionable, relevant information." If notion of Sales intelligence CRM, we could also state that Salesforce follows Sales intelligence CRM approach, since it is technology to help salespeople keep up to date with clients, prospect data and drive business and it provides real-time analysis of current sales data and assists with suggesting and delivering actionable, relevant information.

If we had to choose one approach of the four mentioned, what should have been the correct option if there is no clear statement about this from Salesforce representatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discard the last one for being too new, abstract, and poor-documented. It could be the future, but no the present.

Besides, I do not think that the third approach is correct, since in many cases Salesforce is connected to external Applications in order to analise data. Salesforce is very good with reports but I think that is not the key point.

So, for me, the most appropriate approach would be the first one (I include the second in the first one), Salesforce is good case of operational CRM, with many tools and utilities to manage clients and related entitites (including automatising sales process).

Comment: You're welcome. This is only my personal opinion. It would be great if more people comment.